# Performance issue on SQLite closure table implementation

Tags: performance, sqlite, hierarchical-data

I start by saying that I am fairly new to SQL and database systems, so please excuse me for any possible noobie mistakes that I may be doing.

I am using a closure table to insert hierarchical data in a SQLite database. I am using C# (.NET 4.6.1) and SQLite precompiled 32-bit DLL (x86) for SQLite version 3.26.0. The hierarchical data inserted contains ~240000 elements, and the max tree depth is not greater than 7.

My hierarchical element table is:

`CREATE TABLE element (elementId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, parentId INTEGER, elementName TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES element(elementId));`

And my closure table is defined by:

`CREATE TABLE hierarchy (parentId INTEGER, childId INTEGER, depth INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(parentId) REFERENCES element(elementId), FOREIGN KEY(childId) REFERENCES element(elementId));`

The elements are inserted using a classical stack, which begins with the “root” element, to which the element’s members are added during the treatment inside a transaction using:

`INSERT INTO element VALUES (<ELEMENT_ID>, <PARENT_ID>'<ELEMENT_NAME');`

And I initialize the closure table with the “self” relationship, using:

`INSERT INTO hierarchy(parentId, childId, depth) VALUES (<ELEMENT_ID>, <ELEMENT_ID>, 0);`

These inserts cause no issues, taking a few seconds to execute.

Next, I go through all the elements again using the same stack method to build the closure table (NOTE: I could probably do this at the same time of the previous instructions, however I do it on a separate loop to isolate the performance issue) using the following code (inside another transaction):

`INSERT INTO hierarchy SELECT p.parentId, c.childId, p.depth+c.depth+1 FROM hierarchy p, hierarchy c WHERE p.childId=<PARENT_ID> AND c.parentId=<ELEMENT_ID>;`

However, this query takes HOURS, maybe even days, to execute. It's execution time is also increasingly longer. I know that it inserts a lot of elements in the closure table (one entry per relationship between the current element and all its ascendants), but I wish to know if anything can be done to improve the performance here?

Thanks

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Currently I have no indexes (apart from the one created automatically on the primary key `elementId` on the `element` table). Do you think adding indexes to other items can improve the performance ?

Comment: Yeah, no indexes goes a long way to explaining slow queries. I'd probably add ones on heirarchy's child and parent IDs (and rewrite that query to use proper `JOIN` syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need indexes on child keys and parent keys. Also wrap everything in a transaction.

Better yet, use a single recursive CTE to generate the closure table, something like

```
with recursive
closure as (
    select elementId, elementId as parentId, 0 as depth from element
    union all
    select closure.elementId, element.parentId, 1 + depth as depth
    from closure, element where closure.parentId = element.elementId
)
select * from closure
```

To actually create the table use something like `create table hierarchy as` to put the above result into a table.

Comment: After adding some indexes to the tables and adding a transaction to the query code, the performance difference is HUGE! Thank you all for the tips.